# PyCrypto AES encryption for Server-Client comm

Tags: cryptography, aes

I'm developing a simple secure data exchange between Server-Client and having some problems at the time of implementing AES.

I've already implemented the Shared Key exchange (with public key crypto) and it works fine. The idea in my head was (pseudocode):

```
SERVER
ciphertext = AES.encrypt(sharedKey,data)
send(ciphertext)

CLIENT
ciphertext = receive()
plaintext = AES.decrypt(sharedKey,ciphertext)
```

And voilà. When I tried to implement that, I first found that there was an IV. I first tried setting it to all zeros, like this:

```
self.cipher = AES.new(self.Kshared, AES.MODE_CFB, '0000000000000000')
while( there is data to send ):
    ciphertext = self.cipher.encrypt(data)
    self.sendData(ciphertext)
```

Then, in the Client:

```
cipher = AES.new(Ksecreta, AES.MODE_CFB,'0000000000000000')
while( there is data to receive ):
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt('0000000000000000'+data)[16:]
```

This works fine for the FIRST message, but not for the rest. I assume my problem might has something to do with the IV but I have no idea. Plus, the first implementation I found used a salt to generate another key and also a random IV but the problem is that the client has no idea of which salt/IV is the Server using. I guess you could send that via public key crypto but I first want a simple working AES crypto.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For your decryption code, there's no need to prepend the cipher text with the IV. Have you tried just `plaintext = cipher.decrypt(data)`?

It's safe to transmit the IV in clear text. So you can just generate it randomly, then send it along with the ciphertext outside of the communication. Something like `self.sendData(iv + ciphertext)` and later `iv = data[:16]` and `ciphertext = data[16:]`

Another common thing to consider is encoding - some transport formats don't play well with sending raw byes (which can include NULL characters). It's common to encode the ciphertext into base64 for transport. If you need that, look into `base64.b64encode` and `base64.b64decode`